# How to manage content of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to **manage the content of Google Chrome extension via javascript**, let's say jQuery. I have applied jQuery and now I know how to **manage page's content**. But I don't understand how **to manipulate html in red box** like in my example bellow:

[image]

Comment: Well, I don't know how to manipulate extension popup page.. Red box - is just css, but I can apply any javascript..

Comment: It isn't too broad, I asked a specific question.

Comment: Well, can you give me a link that answers my question?

Comment: Can you see red box at the right top corner of my screen? I have a custom script that uses jQuery inside. And I would like to write some custom script which will make red box to be green (let's say). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, shall I write this code in main html file? Main - I mean html that is responsible for popup. I've tried write same code in external file and include this file in manifest file - it doesn't work for me.

Comment: you havent showed what you tried.

Comment: To be more specific, post your manifest, and post the code for your popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add javascript code to the extension popup put it in a separate `popup.js` file and reference it in your `popup.html`.

```
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will execute `popup.js` after the popup document has been completely loaded so you don't have to wrap the code in `$(function() { .... })` or `$(document).ready(function() { .... })`.

Then you can use jQuery as usual: `$('#id').css('background', 'green')`.